# Let $X$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ consisting of points whose coordinates are both irrational. Prove that $X$ is path-connected

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

I have to prove that if $X$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ consisting of points whose coordinates are both irrational then $X$ will be path-connected.

I think that it isn't connected by arcs, but I don't know how prove it.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.  **You can't prove this** because that's wrong**. Please add context to your question by showing us your attempted proof, like "let $\phi:[0,1]\to X$ be a continuous path, then each component $x(t),y(t)$ of $\phi(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: @AjayKumarNair what do you mean with ''take any line passing through a point in X''? Can you explain it better, please?

Comment: Any path starting from a point in $X$ contains a point in the complement of $X$. Thus, it is not path connected.

Comment: @AjayKumarNair Why any path starting from a point in X contains a point in the complement of X?

Comment: @AjayKumarNair You should give an official answer to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: $\mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P}$ (where $\mathbb{P}$ are the irrationals) is totally disconnected as the product of two totally disconnected spaces. You probably meant that $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$ is (path-)connected and this *is* true, but that set is the set of points with at least one irrational coordinate, not those with *only* irrational coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

As $X$ is disconnected by

$$ \{ (x,y) \in X : 0 < y \} $$

and
$$ \{ (x,y) \in X : 0 > y \} $$

$X$ cannot be path connected.

Comment: do you mean zero<y and zero>y?

Comment: Perhaps the proposer mis-interpreted  a Q of proving that $\Bbb R^2$ \ $ \Bbb Q^2$ is path-connected......+1

Comment: @Giusy.  Small o, large O, zero 0.

Comment: Yes, any removal of countably many point leaves a path connected subspace. @DanielWainfleet

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\sqrt2$, $\sqrt 3$, $e$, $\pi$ are irrational and that $e<3<\pi$.

Assume $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to X$, $t\mapsto \langle \gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t)\rangle$ is a path from $\gamma(0)=\langle\sqrt 2,e\rangle\in X$ to $\gamma(1)=\langle \sqrt 3,\pi\rangle$. Then $\gamma_2$ is continuous and by the Inermediate Value Theorem, there exists a $t^*\in[0,1]$ with $\gamma_2(t^*)=3$. It follows that $\gamma(t^*)\notin X$, contradiction.